# How can I cat a remote file to read the parameters in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

How can I `cat` a remote file? Currently, it works for local files only.

```
#!/bin/bash
regex='url=(.*)'
# for i in $(cat /var/tmp/localfileworks.txt);
for i in $(cat http://localhost/1/downloads.txt);
do
        echo $i;
        # if [[ $i =~ $regex ]]; then
        #echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        #fi
done
```

> cat: http://localhost/1/downloads.txt: No such file or directory

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of `cat`, which reads a file from the file-system, use `wget -O- -q`, which reads a document over HTTP and writes it to standard output:

```
for i in $(wget -O- -q http://localhost/1/downloads.txt)
```

(The `-O...` option means "write to the specified file", where `-` is standard output; the `-q` option means "quiet", and disables lots of logging that would otherwise go to standard error.)

Answer (score 24):

You can use `curl`:

```
curl http://localhost/1/downloads.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

Why are you using a URL to copy from the local machine?  Can't you just cat directly from the file?

If you **are** doing this from a remote machine and not localhost, then as far as I know you can't pass a URL to cat.

I would try something like this:

```
scp username@hostname:/filepath/downloads.txt /dev/stdout
```

As someone else mentioned you could also use **wget** instead of **scp**.